# Dynamically added Gridster widget can't close

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, gridster

I have added a dynamic gridster widget with a close button.

```
gridster.add_widget('<li id="wdg_news" data-row="3" data-col="5" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="3" class="tile-orange" data-ng-hide="!news.length"> <div class="db-wid"><div class="db-title"> Newss <a href="#" class="db-ctrl"><i class="icon-close"></i></a></div><div class="db-content cus_scroll" style="height:304px;"> <div class="w-list"> <c:forEach items="${newsList}" var="news"><div><a href="/news/{{ne.id}}"  class="w-font-s f-white">${news.date} - ${news.summery}</a></div></c:forEach></div></div></div> </li>', 2, 3);
```

all the data is getting loaded to it without any problem and when i click the close button it goes to login screen insted of calling the javascipt.

```
// Remove Grid
$(".db-ctrl").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var parentLi = $(this).parents("li");
    var eq_val = $(".gridster ul li").index(parentLi);
    gridster.remove_widget($('.gridster li').eq(eq_val));
    console.log(eq_val);
    saveGrid();
})
```

This doesnt happen to already created widgets. Only to ones which created dynamically using `gridster.add_widget` method.

Please Help in this matter. Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is that instead of `.on("click")` you need to use `.delegate("click")`.

[`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) listens for elements that already exist in the DOM. [`.delegate`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) listens for elements that already exist in the DOM and are added in the future (e.g. when you dynamically add a widget).

So you just need to modify your click handler

```
$(".gridster").delegate("click", ".db-ctrl", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var parentLi = $(this).parents("li");
    var eq_val = $(".gridster ul li").index(parentLi);
    gridster.remove_widget($('.gridster li').eq(eq_val));
    console.log(eq_val);
    saveGrid();
})
```